# Ensure set number of <td> elements created when iterating through object with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I have a table that is 6 columns. The 4 columns are `year` `1st place` `2nd place`, `3rd place`, and `semi-finalist`.

I'm iterating through an object that looks something like this:

```html
 data = "2016": {
              "year": 2016,
              "event_id": "532867b3-5039-11eb-8917-080027315160",
              "event_season_id": "568df6a7-5039-11eb-8917-080027315160",
              "event_name": "World Ultimate & Guts Championships",
              "event_location": null,
              "placements": {
                "DNF": {
                  "d2dda4b0-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160": {
                    "team": "Democratic Republic of Congo",
                    "team_location": null,
                    "team_season_id": "d2dda4b0-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160",
                    "event_team_placement_id": 5266
                  }
                },
                "1": {
                  "d239d360-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160": {
                    "team": "USA",
                    "team_location": null,
                    "team_season_id": "d239d360-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160",
                    "event_team_placement_id": 5236
                  }
                },
                "2T": {
                  "d23ef304-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160": {
                    "team": "Japan",
                    "team_location": null,
                    "team_season_id": "d23ef304-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160",
                    "event_team_placement_id": 5237
                  }
                },
                "2T": {
                  "d2441dbb-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160": {
                    "team": "Australia",
                    "team_location": null,
                    "team_season_id": "d2441dbb-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160",
                    "event_team_placement_id": 5238
                  }
                },
                "3": {
                  "d2441dbb-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160": {
                    "team": "Australia",
                    "team_location": null,
                    "team_season_id": "d2441dbb-5040-11eb-8917-080027315160",
                    "event_team_placement_id": 5238
                  }
                },
              }
```

That I am iterating through via an `*ngFor` to create a table. Each row of the table should be 1 `year` of the JSON object I have. The first column shows the year, the 2nd-4th columns show the teams that placed 1st-3rd. It should not show any team who is marked as "DNF" or "DQ". If two teams tie, they should instead both be printed in the same column, rather than 2 separate columns. My problem is that in the case two teams have tied, I end up missing a column of data. How can I create an empty `<td>` element even if there is no 4th place finisher?
Here is my HTML

```html
<tr *ngFor='let year_placement of data | keyvalue'>
  <td>{{year_placement.key}}</td>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let placement of year_placement.value.placements | keyvalue'>
    <td *ngIf="placement.key != 'DQ' && placement.key != 'DNF' ">
      <span *ngFor="let team of placement.value | keyvalue; let team_idx = index">
          <span *ngIf='team_idx>=1'>/ </span>{{team.value.team}}  
      </span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

I've included a screenshot of what my table currently looks like to give an idea of the issue.
[image]

As you can see, in 1983, 1984, and 1985, teams tied for 3rd place, leaving me with an empty "semi finalist" column. How can I create an empty `<td>` to make the table full? I plan on adding a few more columns later on, so if I am missing columns, some data won't line up.

Here is a brief example of my issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jkqjhz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Move your `*ngIf` from `td` to `span`

Comment: Could you please add minimal reproducible example, f.e. a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/), so it's easier to provide a solution for your question.

Comment: @Justinas wouldn't that cause an issue if I have multiple teams that are "DNF" or "DQ"? I want to create exactly 5 <td> elements every time, even if there are 100 teams that are "DQ" or "DNF".

Comment: @Roy https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jkqjhz?file=src/app/app.component.html.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add an else clause in your *ngIf? an  inside your  with de if/else

[https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf][1]